# Passing a class containing overridden virtual methods to a dll

Tags: delphi, dll, overriding, virtual

I have an application and a dll, both written in Delphi 2006.

I have an class that descends from a base class and overrides several virtual methods.

The class is passed to the DLL via an exported method, the exported method only knows about the base class. I call the methods on the class from within the DLL the overridden methods are not invoked.

Is there something I need to do to get this to work? is is it simply not possible?

Comment: The first question is: Why are you using a DLL and not a Package/BPL?

Comment: I didn't write the DLL or the application originally but I need to pass a class into it.

Comment: Please show the actual code that is not working.

Comment: @no spoon: Let me get this right: The DLL expects a class instance as parameter to one of its functions and you pass (an instance of) a descendant of that class, with overridden virtual functions, right?

Comment: There are no technical details in this question that would allow you to answer it conclusively.   David's advice is good, and is probably correct, but this question is too vague to be definitively answered, other than saying "no, you can't do this, if I understand you correctly, except that your question is so vague that I can't be sure". Voted to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't create an object in one module and call its methods in a different module. By module I mean .exe/.dll.

If you wish to cross boundaries like this, then you need to use packages, COM or free functions. Packages look alluring but bind you into using the same compiler for all packages in the system. If that is not restrictive to you then go ahead and use packages. Otherwise use  COM or free functions.

Comment: What do you mean by free functions?

Comment: I mean functions that are not part of a class. If you are importing from a DLL, you simply cannot create an object on one side of the boundary and call its methods on the other side.

Comment: Yes, you can call call class methods over the DLL boundary, especially since both EXE and DLL are written with the same compiler. A better choice would be to use an Interface instead of a base class, though.

Comment: @David: or interfaces. Or is that what you meant with COM?

Comment: @Remy: calling class methods is still a bit tricky, as the class on the caller side is not necssarily the same as the one on the DLL side. Static class methods would be fine, though. But "free" functions are preferrable, IMO. One would simply have to "flatten" the object, i.e. write a "free" function or procedure for each method of the class.

Comment: I would have called them "plain old procedures and functions without classes".

Comment: @Warren It's strange that this concept doesn't have a single well known name that we can all agree on!

Comment: I personally resent the ubiquity of OOP. Like it was the best (or even only) way to write good code.  In some cases, OOP is the opposite of helpful.